# find_element_by_class_name does not work with Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to fill out a form, using Selenium and Python.

I am using `find_element_by_class_name` and also `find_element_by_css_selector` in the following code snippets and it is not working. I have no idea why as with Java it works.

code:

```
url = 'https://service.mail.com/registration.html'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/xxxxx/code/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.Required.userdata-firstname').send_keys("james")
```

result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "captcha_createMailBoxes.py", line 51, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.Required.userdata-firstname').send_keys("james")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <li class="Required userdata-firstname"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

code:

```
url = 'https://service.mail.com/registration.html'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/xxxxx/code/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("userdata-firstname").send_keys("james")
```

result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "captcha_createMailBoxes.py", line 54, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("userdata-firstname").send_keys("james")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <li class="Required userdata-firstname"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

Can anyone assist with that? I REALLY do not want to work with Java on that.....

Comment: *How* is it now working? Is there an error?

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

`find_element_by_class_name` receives one class as parameter. `"Required userdata-firstname"` is two classes. Either use one of them

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('Required')
# or
driver.find_element_by_class_name('userdata-firstname')
```

Or use `css_selector` if you want both

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.Required.userdata-firstname')
```

Comment: Tried your suggestions but got errors, please see my updated post. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the CSS element you are referring to in your example is a `li` element. you can not fill an `li` element with text. you need to fill an `input` field. these fields have `value_name` attributes set at random to prevent bots from using them. you can try using the `id` attribute instead.

`driver.find_element_by_id('idf').send_keys('james')`

edit: you can also try xpath if the id changes. you could do something like:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="Required userdata-firstname"]/div/span/input').send_keys('james')`

Comment: the problem is that id is also random and changed every few minutes....

Comment: it looks like as of now the id hasn't changed. i'll edit my answer to include an xpath option